# How do I use my f-1 - f12 keys without pressing FN on Windows 7 using bootcamp on a Macbook Pro?

Tags: windows-7

How do I use my <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> keys without pressing <kbd>FN</kbd> in Windows 7 using bootcamp on a Macbook Pro?

Answer (score 14):

Once you have installed the keyboard driver, run regedit using Start Menu >> Run and then navigate to:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\KeyMagic`

There will be a 'Binary' entry `OSXFnBehavior` with the value `01`.
Change this to `00`.

Afterwards my function keys worked as function keys without having to press <kbd>fn</kbd>. You need to unplug and plug the keyboard or restart the computer to make this work after editing — the driver doesn't check this value continuously.

Comment: @Rustem please don't add your different solutions to others' posts, especially when they are incorrect.

Comment: In recent version of Windows/Bootcamp/keyboards this solution does not work but inspire me to find the solution searching for other occurrence of "OSXFnBehavior" in antire registry. I Find it on HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Apple Inc.\Apple Keyboard Support. Change or create a REG_DWORD named OSXFnBehavior with value 0. Unplug the keyboard and you get what you want.

Comment: This works **perfectly** with an Apple Aluminium USB Keyboard model A1242 on a Windows 10 PC after installing [these](http://pc.cd/94j) drivers in order to get home, end, page up and page down working via `fn + arrows` keys. 
Thank you, I searched _hours_ before finding this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the full Boot Camp driver suite loaded (and assuming it's functioning properly under Windows 7), there should be a checkbox under Keyboard for "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys", same as there is for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) in Windows 7 and remap them. I'm not sure what your laptop uses them as initially, but you can find their scan code with this script:

```
SetFormat, Integer, Hex
Gui +ToolWindow -SysMenu +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, Font, s14 Bold, Arial
Gui, Add, Text, w100 h33 vSC 0x201 +Border, {SC000}
Gui, Show,, % "// ScanCode //////////"
Loop 9
  OnMessage( 255+A_Index, "ScanCode" ) ; 0x100 to 0x108
Return

ScanCode( wParam, lParam ) {
 Clipboard := "SC" SubStr((((lParam>>16) & 0xFF)+0xF000),-2)
 GuiControl,, SC, %Clipboard%
}
```

then remap like so:

```
SC##::F##
```

replace the first ## with the scancode of the key, and the second ## with the function key. For example, if F1 sent SC03B, you'd use `SC03B::F1`.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Windows on your Mac, click. in the right side of the taskbar, click the Boot Camp icon , then choose Boot Camp Control Panel.
2. If a User Account Control dialog appears, click Yes.
3. Click Keyboard.
4. Select or deselect “Use all F1, F2 etc.

This works fine for windows 10 macbook pro

[image]