# Change function keys in Windows 7 (bootcamp)

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp, function-keys

I am gaming on windows 7 with my Mac. The problem is that the function keys are set as the mac function keys. For example if I need to drink a healing potion in the game by hitting F1, my computer adjusts the brightness.

Is there any way to change the function keys. I know how to do this on the mac side of my computer but since most of my gaming is on Windows. I will need to know how to make these changes in windows 7.

Comment: a lot of games have a setup screen, where you can change the key bindings. What game(s) are you using?

Comment: I'm playing a lot of games.  Most of them don't allow key remapping.  A lot of dollar value of games.  So I am looking to remap keys in windows 7 rather to solve the problem of games which do not have remapping.

Comment: so, you're actually running these games under Windows, not Mac?

Comment: Yes Nate I am running these games with Windows.  I know hop to use them as default function keys on the mac side.  But on the windows 7 side I do not know how to do this.

Comment: I figured it out.  You hit control panel then system and security then bootcamp then keyboard then there is a checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response though.. In an internet search I couldn't find the answer but then I just started messing around the control panel.

Comment: Please post this as an answer to your own question and accept it once possible (clicking the checkbox next to it) to help others that might have the same problem.

Comment: I think you guys want to change the title back as it is only relevant for windows 7 users who are using bootcamp.  At least to my knowledge.  Its not a key rebinding thing it just reverts the function keys back to normal for a mac keyboard.

Comment: I'm not allowed to answer my own question until I have 100 reputation points.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function keys not working in Mac Keyboard on windows](http://superuser.com/questions/217043/function-keys-not-working-in-mac-keyboard-on-windows)

Answer (score 12):

Go to `Control Panel -> System -> Security -> Bootcamp` and you can configure the keyboard from there.

*posted @Claudius's comments as an answer; [see here](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-i/1931#1931)*

Comment: And just in case here it is how to do that in case of Parallels http://kb.parallels.com/en/114309

Comment: And if you don't want to use/install the bootcamp controle panel you can edit one key in the registry to achieve the same: change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\KeyMagic\OSXFnBehavior` to `00` and unplug/replug the keyboard. (http://superuser.com/a/510692/180594)

Answer (score 4):

I have Boot Camp and wanted to use the F keys without pressing fn, however, the answer listed here was not exactly accurate and took me on a vexing detour.

[You cannot click through any path/directory "System -> Security -> Bootcamp"]

Here are the exact corrected steps:

Go to **Control Panel -> Bootcamp**

Select the **"Keyboard"** tab and then check-mark the option to **"Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"**

Comment: From the Windows menu 'Search Programs and Files' option type 'boot' and Windows finds 'Boot Camp', then as above (for those that cannot find BC through the Control Panel. Like me.)

Answer (score 4):

If you can't install Bootcamp itself for whatever reason (in my case, I'm just using an apple keyboard on a PC rather than dual-booting a mac), you can still get your function keys working correctly using the [boot camp drivers pack on Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macoscomponents).

Within the zip file, the `BootCamp\Drivers\Apple` folder contains two files of interest:

- `AppleKeyboardInstaller64.exe` will install the driver to enable play/pause and the other magic function keys on your keyboard. Unfortunately it will also turn off FnLock, so you won't be able to use F8 as F8 by default.
- `BootCamp.msi` is where the BootCamp control panel lives. You'll need to install it manually if you want the Fn keys settings to actually work.

To install the Boot Camp control panel

1. Copy `BootCamp.msi` out of the zip file to someplace easy to remember.
2. Start a command prompt **as administrator**.
3. `cd` to whatever folder contains `BootCamp.msi` and run this command:

   ```
   msiexec /i BootCamp.msi
   ```

   - If you get an error about needing to run this package "from setup.exe," double check that you're actually running *msiexec* as administrator.
   - An error about missing files can be safely ignored.
4. Let the installer reboot your machine

This will also have the side effect of installing Apple's boot selector service, which is functionally useless on a non-Mac machine. Fortunately, it's not necessary for the keyboard drivers to actually work. To remove it, after you've rebooted, open another command prompt **as administrator** and use this command:

```
sc delete AppleOssMgr
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can not open Bootcamp from Control panel after installation according to @Dan,

1. Run CMD as administrator
2. Run following command:

   "C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe" /trustlevel:0x20000 AppleControlPanel.exe

and then check-mark the option to "**Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys**"